# sequence associated with a snowflake table

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, database-schema

For any snowflake table how can I find the sequence associated with all its columns? I tried to look into INFORMATION_SCHEMA but couldn't find any clue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way you could capture is if you have defined the Default for the column to be a value entered by the sequence then you can search by the following query SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_DEFAULT LIKE '%.NEXTVAL';.  But if you are entering the data through a Function or a stored procedure then it may not work, also if you are entering the data through a code which is not stored in Snowflake then it is difficult to find out.

Comment: @hkandpal, you are a life saver!

Comment: Hi Anand, one crude way is to use the QUERY_HISTORY table functions provided by Snowflake and search for the NEXTVAL word in the QUERY_TEXT column and identify the SQLs which are using the sequence. (Don't know if it will cover all your tables or sequences as  if queries which are run outside the time frame of data captured  by the functions may not be captured in the output, but this will capture all the SQL even if run by a code not in Snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in `columns` view in Information Schema
using column "IS_IDENTITY"

Reference : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html